# JSP shows wrong (old) values

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, javabeans, server-side

Following Problem:

I am using a Servlet as a Controller, JSB for the Model and Java Beans for the Information. Here the code:

HTML/JSP:

```
<table summary="Diese Tabelle zeigt Informationen zum aktuellen Spiel">
                            <jsp:useBean id="game" class="model.Spiel" scope="session"/>
                            <tr><th id="leaderLabel" class="label">F&uuml;hrender</th><td id="leader" class="data"><%= game.getLeader() %></td></tr>
                            <tr><th id="roundLabel" class="label">Runde</th><td id="round" class="data"><%= game.getRound() %></td></tr>
                            <tr><th id="timeLabel" class="label">Zeit</th><td id="time" class="data"><%= game.getTime() %></td></tr>
                            <tr><th id="computerScoreLabel" class="label">W&uuml;rfelergebnis <em>Super C</em></th><td id="computerScore" class="data"><%= game.getComputerScore() %></td></tr>
                        </table>
```

HTML Servlet Call:

```
<a id="dice" href="GameServlet?action=wurfeln" tabindex="4">
                            <img id="diceImage" src="img/wuerfel1.png" alt="W&uuml;rfel mit einer Eins" />
                        </a>
```

Servlet:

```
if(action.equals("wurfeln")){
            // Get right game for the session
            Spiel game;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            if(sessions.getGame(session)==null) {
                sessions.newSessions(session);
                game = sessions.getGame(session);
            }
            else {
                game = sessions.getGame(session);
            }

            // Runt methods on game
            game.setSpielerScore(); //Spieler würfelt
            game.setComputerScore(); //Computer würfelt

            // Load new JSB
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/table.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
```

Java Bean: (Game)

```
package model;
import java.util.Random;

public class Spiel {
    private int Runde;
    private String Zeit;
    private int Spieler_Feld;
    private int Spieler_Wurfelergebnis;
    private String Spieler_Name;
    private int Computer_Feld;
    private int Computer_Wurfelergebnis;
    private String Computer_Name;
    private Random x;

    public Spiel() {
        this.Runde         = 1;
        this.Zeit          = "00:00";
        this.Spieler_Feld  = 1;
        this.Computer_Feld = 1;
        this.Spieler_Name  = "Super Mario";
        this.Computer_Name = "Super C";
        this.x             = new Random();
        this.Spieler_Wurfelergebnis  = 0;
        this.Computer_Wurfelergebnis = 0;
    }

    public void setRound(int round) {
        this.Runde = round;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.Zeit = time;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return this.Zeit;
    }

    public int getRound() {
        return this.Runde;
    }

    public void newRound() {
        this.Runde += 1;
    }

    public String getLeader() {
        if(this.Spieler_Feld > this.Computer_Feld) {
            return this.Spieler_Name;
        }
        else if(this.Spieler_Feld < this.Computer_Feld){
            return this.Computer_Name;
        }
        else {
            return "beide";
        }
    }

    public void setSpielerScore() {
        //Spieler würfelt
        //this.Spieler_Wurfelergebnis = this.x.nextInt(3)+1;
        this.Spieler_Wurfelergebnis = 3;
    }

    public void setComputerScore() {
        //Computer würfelt
        //this.Computer_Wurfelergebnis = this.x.nextInt(3)+1;
        this.Computer_Wurfelergebnis = 2;
    }

    public int getSpielerScore() {
        return this.Spieler_Wurfelergebnis;
    }

    public int getComputerScore() {
        return this.Computer_Wurfelergebnis;
    }
}
```

Java Bean: (Session)

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class Sessions {
    HashMap<HttpSession, Spiel> sessions = new HashMap<HttpSession, Spiel>();

    public void newSessions(HttpSession s) {
        if(!sessions.containsKey(s)) {
            Spiel newgame = new Spiel();
            sessions.put(s, newgame);
        }
    }

    public Spiel getGame(HttpSession s) {
        Spiel spiel = sessions.get(s);
        if (spiel != null) {
            return spiel;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem what I am experiencing is that with the new load of the JSP in the Servlet (Request dispatcher .... ) it should actually show updated values in the new JSP. Since with `game.setSpielerScore()` it changes some variables, but it continues to show the values set with the constructer call.

I have three possible ideas why this happens:

1) Something is wrong in the JSP Code, it possible doesnt gather the values of the right object.

2) Something is wrong with the Session JavaBeans, it doesnt give back the right game for the session or something.

3) It doesn`t update the variables of the Game object correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `game` attribute needs to be set in the request.

```
if(action.equals("wurfeln")){
            // Get right game for the session
            Spiel game;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            if(sessions.getGame(session)==null) {
                sessions.newSessions(session);
                game = sessions.getGame(session);
            }
            else {
                game = sessions.getGame(session);
            }

            // Runt methods on game
            game.setSpielerScore(); //Spieler würfelt
            game.setComputerScore(); //Computer würfelt

            request.setAttribute("game", game);//set the game in the request.

            // Load new JSB
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/table.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
```

**JSP**

```
<jsp:useBean id="game" class="model.Spiel" scope="request"/>
```

Comment: Glad, I could help.  One thing to note, you should see the modifications to the game across sessions even though we don't store the game in session. Since you are working with a reference to the object, the changes will be made on the actual object, this is similar to how Java passes objects to methods, passing a copy of the reference.  See: http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html  Given this we can simply put the game in the request, which is where I try to push all information prior to relying on session.